# Implementing a simple Dictionary in TypeScript 1.8

Tags: javascript, dictionary, typescript

I am trying to find a simple way to implement a `Dictionary` in TypeScript 1.8. There are several implementation suggestions on the web, but the most attractive looks like this:

```
var MyDictionary: { [id: number]: string };
```

Unfortunately, I don't really understand what this code means. `MyDictionary` is of type `{ [id: number]: string }`, but what on earth does that mean? And, in turn, what does `[id: number]: string` mean? Is this also a type? I am guessing the `id` is the key, but the value appears to be nameless.

How do I, for example, iterate over the dictionary and extract the key/value pairs? I use underscore.js quite liberally in my code so suggestions for iteration and manipulation using this library appreciated.

Comment: Oo, indexable type, perfect answer thank you! But how would one go about iterating over such a collection, retrieving both the 'key' (or index?) and value?

Comment: Aha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174182/typescript-looping-through-a-dictionary. I shall try this. Pity you didn't answer the question, I could've marked it as "answered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the right construct to use for a dictionary; it's called an indexable type (or indexer) and the docs can be found [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

The basic concept is to overlay type constraints on a plain JS object, using the object key names as dictionary keys and specifying the type of objects it contains. As such, you can use standard JS object iteration techniques like `for...in` for indexable types.