# ES7 Object.entries() in TypeScript not working

Tags: typescript

I have an issue with transpiling ES7 code with TypeScript. This code:

```
const sizeByColor = {
    red: 100,
    green: 500,
};

for ( const [ color, size ] of Object.entries(sizeByColor) ) {
    console.log(color);
    console.log(size);
}
```

gives the error:

`TypeError: Object.entries is not a function`

**TypeScript v2.0.3**

tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "lib": [ "es2017" ],
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
],
"include": [
    "./node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "./src/**/*.ts"
]
}
```

I want to iterate trough object with `Object.entries()`, so I assigned internal definitions `"lib": [ "es2017" ]`, but still, typescript wont allow me to transpile it.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please introduce your question with... a question or an entry to your problem, with detail about what you are using. Add examples of what you did, what worked and what didn't. Thanks

Comment: Yes :) Sorry for being a bit pedantic, but don't worry I too had my lot of pokes when I came here ;) Don't forget to upvote all what is relevant/helped you and to mark as accepted when an answer fits your needs. Thanks !

Comment: if you are using angular 2+ you need to add import 'core-js/es7/object'; to your polyfills.ts file

Comment: add "es2019" to ur tsconfig lib array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hm, it looks i forgot to inject `core-js` polyfill to `Object.entries`. import `'core-js/fn/object/entries';` With this polyfill transpilation works, but IDE is still complaining about it. When I include `@types/core-js` directly, IDE is ok, but Typescript will crash due to duplicate declarations in "lib/es2017".. It looks like IDE (WebStorm) cant handle "lib" settings inside `tsconfig.json`

**EDIT:**
Yey, i tried to modify WebStorm settings, and after set "Use TypeScript service (experimental)" to true, everything is ok !

Comment: alright help me out with a little further explaining.  Where are you importing 'core-js/fn/object/entries'?

Comment: @Winnemucca Setting `es2017.object` in Typescript config provides just declaration of `Object.entries`. If you are in environment that doesn't actually have this method (eg. Node.js 6), you need to use polyfill. `core-js` library provides various polyfills.

Answer (score 32):

I can reproduce your problem when I have a global compiler but not a local one in the `./node_modules`.

In my case compiler just does not know which tsconfig.json file to use. Pointing it to a particular `tsconfig.json` file helps:

```
tsc  --project ./tsconfig.json
```

I have also added `dom` option to the lib, because `es2017` does not recognize console:

```
"lib": [
    "es2017",
    "dom"
]
```

Comment: I had to add `"es2017"` as a preset in `.babelrc` as well as the lib option in this answer

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to include the full set of **ECMAScript 2017 (ES8)** in your set of libraries, then you can also use `es2017.object` to just satisfy the resolution of `Object.entries` and related.

Here is a minimal working example:

**src/index.ts**

```
const sizeByColor = {
  red: 100,
  green: 500,
};

for (const [color, size] of Object.entries(sizeByColor)) {
  console.log(color);
  console.log(size);
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016", "es2017.object"],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**Note:** If `"target"` is set to `"es6"`, then TypeScript uses by default the following `"lib"` entries (if none are specified): `["dom", "dom.iterable", "es6", "scripthost"]`.

The library defaults get overwritten when setting `"lib"` manually, that's why I needed to add `"dom"` (to use `console.log` in my code) and `"es6"` to demonstrate the usage of ES6 and partial ES8 (`"es2017.object"`).

Source: [TypeScript Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me; of course you can change any here for the interface/type that works for you...

```
 for (const [field, values] of Object.entries<any>(filters)) {
```

Comment: I want to do this but with a stricter type...

Answer (score 3):

For a standalone Typescript app, I had to add the lib `es2019.object` to the tsconfig, and import the polyfill to make it work :)

```
import 'core-js/es/object/from-entries';
```