# Best way to process non-ideal JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently attempting to read a `.vdf` file, which is [Valve's proprietary "KeyValue" file format](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/KeyValues). I have found a simple [VDF to JSON converter](https://github.com/rossengeorgiev/vdf-parser) which seems to suit my needs just fine, but the JSON output is formatted in a way that is less than ideal. For example, for the following VDF input:

```
"LibraryFolders"
{
    "TimeNextStatsReport"       "1523464730"
    "ContentStatsID"        "8627456721266182211"
    "1"     "G:\\Steam"
}
```

I get the following JSON output:

```
{
    "LibraryFolders": {
        "1": "G:\\\\Steam",
        "TimeNextStatsReport": "1523464730",
        "ContentStatsID": "8627456721266182211"
    }
}
```

I need a way to grab all variables in the `LibraryFolders` object with a strictly numerical name (1, 2, 3...) and put them into an array, stripping out the `TimeNextStatsReport` and `ContentStatsID` fields. How would one do this?

The output that I would find the easiest to work with would be as follows:

```
{
    "LibraryFolders": [
        "G:\\\\Steam",
        ...
    ]
}
```

With the ellipsis obviously denoting a continuation of any numerically-named fields.

Comment: So you want: `{ "LibraryFolders": ["G:\\\Steam", "1523464730", "8627456721266182211"] }`

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Yes, but with only the numerically-named fields (`"1"`, for example). I don't actually need the `TimeNextStatsReport` or `ContentStatsID` fields, only the ones containing actual folder paths.

Comment: Show the exact output you want, and I will tell you how to do it.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande See my edit.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I need to filter out the `TimeNestStatsReport` and `ContentStatsID` fields, sorry if I wasn't clear :)

Comment: Clear as water now, check my answer.

Comment: Nit: `JSON.parse` (or the JS engine if the "json" is used an Object Literal) is the only "parsing" done.

Comment: @user2864740 Noted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you parse the JSON, we can use a combination of: `Object.entries`, `Array.filter` & `Array.map`, to achieve the desired format.

```js
let object = {
    "LibraryFolders": {
        "1": "G:\\\\Steam",
        "TimeNextStatsReport": "1523464730",
        "ContentStatsID": "8627456721266182211",
        "2": "Other Numeric key",
    }
}

object.LibraryFolders = Object.entries(object.LibraryFolders)
  .filter(([key, value]) => Number(key)) // Filter non numeric keys
  .map(([, value]) => value); // We only keep the value, not the key


console.log(object);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was beginning to question my sanity with how much this was bothering me.

Comment: @IsaacCorbrey a bit shorter alternative `object.LibraryFolders = Object.assign([], object.LibraryFolders).slice(1)`

Comment: @Slai I must say, I'm impressed, never thought of that one.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande @Slai Thank you both so much! Now I just have to figure out why `Object.entries()` and `Object.assign()` both aren't working with TypeScript.

Comment: @IsaacCorbrey take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741428/es7-object-entries-in-typescript-not-working

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Thank you, I forgot to state the lib I was using in my `tsconfig`

Answer (score 0):

here you have a sample code that could do what you want (I think)

```js
//lets take your example object.
let LibraryFolders= {
    "1": "G:\\\\Steam",
    "TimeNextStatsReport": "1523464730",
    "ContentStatsID": "8627456721266182211",
    "2": "kasjfkljaklsjf",
    "1241212213": "alskdjlkasjkladsjasj",
    "123jkjk123123": "aksjdljasdkljklsad",
  };

//we define a function that will do the magic  
function getArrayVersion(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => {
    if (!isNaN(key)) {
      return key
      // return parseInt(key); //in case that you need the INT conversion.
    }
  });
}

//we call the magic
console.log(getArrayVersion(LibraryFolders))
```

Comment: He wants the value, not the key :)

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande thanks for telling me that, good catch. in that case he just need to change the return into this:


return obj[key]

Comment: Still won't work, filter doesn't change the value, it will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would give you anther one-loop sample:

```js
let object = {
        "LibraryFolders": {
            "1": "G:\\\\Steam",
            "TimeNextStatsReport": "1523464730",
            "ContentStatsID": "8627456721266182211",
            "2": "kasjfkljaklsjf",
            "1241212213": "alskdjlkasjkladsjasj",
            "123jkjk123123": "aksjdljasdkljklsad",
        }
    };
    object['LibraryFolders'] = Object.keys(object['LibraryFolders']).reduce((acc, current) => (/^\d+$/.test(current) && acc.push(object['LibraryFolders'][current]), acc), []);
    console.log(object);
```

Comment: of course, you can run it and check if it's desired

Comment: You didn't, in `edited` we can see all your changes, So, your first version wasn't tested at all, so you should say: 'My bad, fixed!' instead of 'Of course'...

Comment: I updated the first version, then saw your first comnent and answere. anyway, you're interesting