# Angular-tree-component how to capture selected nodes through checkbox selection

Tags: typescript, treeview, angular5, angular-components

I'm using angular-tree-component to generate a tree with checkbox options.
HTML

```
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options">
      </tree-root>
```

Typescript:

```
import { ITreeOptions } from 'angular-tree-component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class myComponent {
nodes = [
    {
      name: 'root1',
      children: [
        { name: 'root1_child1' },
        {
          name: 'root1_child2', children: [
            { name: 'grand_child1' },
            { name: 'grand_child2' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'root2',
      children: [
        { name: 'root2_child1' },
        {
          name: 'root2_child2', children: [
            { name: 'grand_child1' },
            { name: 'grand_child2' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  options: ITreeOptions = {
    useCheckbox: true
  };

  optionsDisabled: ITreeOptions = {
    useCheckbox: true,
    useTriState: false
  };
```

So I'm able to select tree nodes (including children) but not able to find any way where I can capture all the selected (checked) nodes and display on another box.[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use "event.treeModel.selectedLeafNodeIds" to get the selected node in tree,

Example:

```
<tree-root [nodes]="treeNode" (select)="onSelect($event)"
    (deselect)="onDeselect($event)" [options]="options"></tree-root>

this.selectedTreeList = Object.entries(event.treeModel.selectedLeafNodeIds)
     .filter(([key, value]) => {
            return (value === true);
      }).map((node) => node[0]);
```

Comment: It works, also i'm getting an array of numbers and not of objects...something like: ["2860399510223", "3897698631848", "9993577998256", "5009898083230", "3866878811722", "1313097673070"]  ....how can I get the objects and not this ?

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo you can remove the last map((node) => node[0]); from the above sample code, it will return you an array of objects :)

Comment: Yep, I solved it with getNodeById with the selectedTreeList :) ...thanks

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo could u tell me what u mentioned in the onSelect event and how to get that value ?

Comment: @Dexter, there are two way we can get the selected item of the tree list, 

1) Only current selected item,

    selectedItem: any;

    onSelect(event) {

    this.selectedItem = event.node.data;
}

2) Get all selected items in one shot, also given in above example,

    this.selectedTreeList = Object.entries(event.treeModel.selectedLeafNodeIds)
     .filter(([key, value]) => {
            return value;
      });

Comment: @nithin below is my stackblitz could u able implement in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zapxko

Comment: have you selected all check boxes by default ?

Comment: Here is the link of new forked,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blq933

 its working see the console, when u select or de-select any item in your list, however, Object. entries method is not available in your stackbliz, if you include some config in your tsconfig file (local project), and utilize second way (shown in my above solution as well) way of getting all item selected in your tree, for more ref

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741428/es7-object-entries-in-typescript-not-working.

hope this solve your issue :)

Answer (score 3):

With reference to above answer to get objects you can use

```
  Object.entries(this.treeModel.selectedLeafNodeIds)
  .filter(([key, value]) => {
    return (value === true);
  })
  .map((id) => {
    let node = this.treeModel.getNodeById(id[0]);
    return node;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using (select) and (deselect) events.
here it is a little example.

```
onSelect(event) {
    try {

      let pushdata: any = [];
      pushdata.push(event.node.data);

      console.log(this.TreeViewData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  }
```

and same as in deselect even you can capture deselected nodes

```
ondeSelect(event) {
        try {

          let pushdata: any = [];
          pushdata.push(event.node.data);

          console.log(this.TreeViewData);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message)
        }
      }
```

Event.node.data will return a list of the array off all the properties you binded.