# How to safely traverse an object's key and print all value by the key in typescript?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am learning typescript and I am trying to define a function to traverse an object's value, but when I do like this, the `tslint` tells me:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)
```

Here is my code:

```
function proxyData(data: object) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key: string) => {
    console.log(data[key]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In typescript object does not have any keys defined by default.
If you want to access the keys on a known structure specify your data object explicitely.

E.g.

```
interface MyData {
  key1: string;
  key2: boolean;
}

function proxyData(data: MyData) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key: string) => {
    console.log(data[key]);
  });
}
```

If you don't want to specify the keys you can give a general index structure

```
interface myData {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Otherwise use `any` instead of `object`.

Since, you try to get the keys and the values, think about using `Object.entries`.

```
function proxyData(data: myData) {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    console.log(key + ':' + value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the object as say,

```
let myDictionary: { [index: string]: any; } = {};
for (let key in myDictionary) 
{
  let value = myDictionary[key];
  // Use `key` and `value` 
}
```

In TS you need to define the Object type even though you do not know the exact type, you can use above dictionary structure

**>= ES 2017:** See here to configure or use [es7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741428/es7-object-entries-in-typescript-not-working/39815452#39815452) and work in typescript

```
 Object.entries(myDictionary).forEach(
  ([key, value]) => console.log(key, value);
);
```