# how to iterate a object array to get key and value in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a object array and would like to get key and value by iterating though it, however I only get 0, 1 as index. anyone know why?

```
const vairable = [{key1: "value1"}, {key2: "value2"}]
Object.keys(vairable).forEach((i: any) => {
    console.log(i); # get 0 and 1, I would like to have key1, key2
});
```

Comment: What is `keySelectors`? You have an array of non-uniform objects in `vairable`. If you want the keys and values of each object, first iterate `vairable`, then use `Object.entries()` to iterate the properties of each object

Comment: @Phil Surprisingly `Object.entries` is not available in typescript it seems

Comment: @Isaac depends on your language level config. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741428/es7-object-entries-in-typescript-not-working

Answer (score 4):

`Object.keys` gives the indices of the array itself, not the objects in the values. Iterate over the values and explore them:

```js
const variable = [{key1: "value1"}, {key2: "value2"}];

for (const value of variable) {
    const firstKey = Object.keys(value)[0];
    console.log(firstKey);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try like this.

```
const vairable = [{key1: "value1"}, {key2: "value2"}]
vairable.forEach(item =>{
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)){
       console.log(key , value)
    }
})
```

it will output :

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this: Loop through array:

```
const vairable = [{key1: "value1"}, {key2: "value2"}]
for(let e of vairable) {
  console.log(Object.keys(e))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Object.keys method work on the Object not on the Arrays. If you want a loop through an Object, Then it will work fine like below,

```js
const keys = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};

Object.keys(keys).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);
});
```