# How to set multiple values at once in react hook form using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have the following interface :

```
export interface DataResponse {
  user_id: string;
  name: string;
  phone_number: string;
  country: string;
}
```

which is used as a type for fetching the data with react query.
I am using useEffect to populate the fields if there is data:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
      Object.entries(userData).forEach(
        ([name, value]) => setValue(name, value));
    }
}, [setValue, userData]);
```

The type of userData is DataResponse... when I set the values with `setState(name, value)` it underlines name and throws the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type | "name" | "phone_number" | "country"
```

Comment: Why you want to update the state while iterating the object ? is setValue for updating a local state ? If so just do `setValue(userData)` and treat your state as an object.

Comment: Its react hook form function

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you can just use RHF's [`reset`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset) method here.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
      reset(userData);
    }
}, [userData, reset]);
```

Comment: the main problem with reset approach is that after this you wont be able to completely reset the form, as the object you pass to reset function becomes the default values

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your comment correctly, but you can pass a config object to `reset`. One of the props is `keepDefaultValues` and prevents overwriting the default values. You can read more about it [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset/).

Answer (score 1):

first: why do you check for `userData`, but than use `userBillingData`?

second: as i dont know what `userBillingData` is, you can use:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
      Object.entries(userBillingData).forEach(
        ([name, value]: any) => setValue(name, value));
    }
}, [setValue, userData]);
```

otherwise you will have to cast the correct type.

[ES7 Object.entries() in TypeScript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741428/es7-object-entries-in-typescript-not-working/39815452#39815452)

Comment: Yeap, sorry userBillingData should be userData.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyof in that case:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
      Object.entries(userBillingData).forEach(
        ([name, value]) => setValue(name as keyof DataResponse, value));
    }
}, [setValue, userData]);
```

Comment: Still throwing an error

Comment: I've successfully did it like this
`setValue(name as keyof FormData, value);`

Answer (score 1):

in case the previous form values are also needed:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
      reset((prev) => ({...prev, ...userData}));
    }
}, [userData, reset]);
```