# tslint / codelyzer / ng lint error: "for (... in ...) statements must be filtered with an if statement"

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-cli, tslint

Lint error message:

> src/app/detail/edit/edit.component.ts[111, 5]: for (... in ...)
>   statements must be filtered with an if statement

Code snippet (It is a working code. It is also available at [angular.io form validation section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html)):

```
for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      // clear previous error message (if any)
      this.formErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get(field);

      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
        for (const key in control.errors) {
          this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
```

Any idea how to fix this lint error?

Comment: Maybe accept an answer?

Answer (score 349, accepted):

To **explain the actual problem** that tslint is pointing out, a quote from 
the JavaScript documentation of the [for...in statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> The loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object
>   itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype
>   (properties closer to the object in the prototype chain override
>   prototypes' properties).

So, basically this means you'll get properties you might not expect to get (from the object's prototype chain).

To solve this we need to iterate only over the objects own properties. We can do this in two different ways (as suggested by @Maxxx and @Qwertiy).

#### First solution

```
for (const field of Object.keys(this.formErrors)) {
    ...
}
```

Here we utilize the [Object.Keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method which returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

#### Second solution

```
for (var field in this.formErrors) {
    if (this.formErrors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this solution we iterate all of the object's properties including those in it's prototype chain but use the [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method, which returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as own (not inherited) property, to filter the inherited properties out.

Comment: I'd like to notice that `Object.keys` is ES5. The only thing from ES6 there is for-of loop. We can iterate array in usual loop from 0 to its length and it would be ES5.

Comment: once more notice: if somehow `this.formErrors` is null, `for...in` just do nothing, while `for ... of Object.keys()` would throw error.

Comment: i am following the second solution but still i see the lint message. Disabled lint for time being.

Comment: Why don't you recommend `Object.keys(obj).forEach( key => {...}) `?

Comment: @BenCarp - it has serious problems when running in an async function, therefore, at least to me, for ... in/of ... are considered more superior. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop#answer-50874507

Comment: note that avoiding null prototypes may be needed in case of using hasOwnProperty prototype method: Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)

Comment: The two solutions will behave differently if the object has numeric keys. Object.keys will numerically sort them, while the plain for in loop will maintain insertion order. Just something to watch out for as it's a bit unexpected.

Answer (score 286):

A neater way of applying @Helzgate's reply is possibly to replace your 'for .. in' with

```
for (const field of Object.keys(this.formErrors)) {
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as not only it solves the problem, it also reduces the amount of boilerplate code compared to additional conditionals such as `if (this.formErrors.hasOwnProperty(field))`.

Comment: Be careful with the answer, it might break your codes. Test after you "fix" it.

Comment: This doesn't actually remove the tslint error for me.

Comment: @HammerN'Songs check that you changed to for *of* instead of for *in*

Comment: same problem here. error is not removed after using this

Comment: remember to change the other line as well to : `for (const key of Object.keys(control.errors)) `

Answer (score 74):

```ts
for (const field in this.formErrors) {
  if (this.formErrors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
```

```js
for (const key in control.errors) {
  if (control.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
```

Answer (score 14):

use Object.keys:

```
Object.keys(this.formErrors).map(key => {
  this.formErrors[key] = '';
  const control = form.get(key);

  if(control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
    const messages = this.validationMessages[key];
    Object.keys(control.errors).map(key2 => {
      this.formErrors[key] += messages[key2] + ' ';
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If the behavior of for(... in ...) is acceptable/necessary for your purposes, you can tell tslint to allow it.

in tslint.json, add this to the "rules" section.

```
"forin": false
```

Otherwise, @Maxxx has the right idea with

```
for (const field of Object.keys(this.formErrors)) {
```

Comment: Editing tslint.json....quick, easy and works great.  Excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think this message is not about avoiding to use `switch`. Instead it wants you to check for `hasOwnProperty`. The background can be read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735184/1374488