# Angular - Determine When A Control Is Added To A FormGroup

Tags: angular

On a AbstractControl, there is an observable property `valueChanges`.  This will fire when a new control is added to the FormGroup but it also fires when a single control value is edited.  I only want to be notified when a control is added so I can call patchValue(state);   Or if there is a way to only patch the values that aren't dirty would work as well.

Comment: what is the exact requirement ?

Comment: Simultaneous updates to state by varying users... Example; during the edit process, if someone else makes changes to the editing state, the user will be notified that the value has changed so they can choose to accept or ignore.

Comment: everytime a control is added you will add it via a method you can get the notification there. Or you want to check if a form control becomes dirty and then trigger update?

Comment: Where does it say valueChanges fires when control is added to FormGroup?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl has booleans for pristine, dirty, touched and untouched

Comment: @JGFMK  check this plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/v7USKj8elVn6wHxKPGe5?p=preview

Comment: hmmm... I guess I could iterate controls of the form group and call patch on them individually if they aren't dirty. Can also send a notification at that time if it is dirty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235156/angular-2-iterate-over-reactive-form-controls

Comment: Thanks guys... guess I just needed someone to talk to  ;)