# Angular form updateValueAndValidity of all children controls

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

In my Angular 4 app, I have a form with several controls.

At some points I need to force the update of their validity, so I'm doing:

```
this.form.get('control1').updateValueAndValidity();
this.form.get('control2').updateValueAndValidity();
this.form.get('control3').updateValueAndValidity();
// and so on....
```

and then:

```
this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

this works fine.

However I was wondering if there is a better way to accomplish the same thing, by just calling one method on the parent form.

According to its [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity), the `updateValueAndValidity()` method:

> By default, it will also update the value and validity of its **ancestors**.

but in my case I need to update the value and validity of its **descendants**. So I can get rid of many lines of code.

Comment: Did you try something to see whether it *does* update its descendants?

Comment: something like ... ?

Comment: ...not calling the descendants' methods directly first? I'd have thought `updateValueAndValidity` *would* also apply to child forms.

Comment: yes of course, and it does not work

Comment: Interesting question. I think it's not available out of the box, there's same issue in this case with `markAsDirty`: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11774 I think you need to do some workaround and iterate the object properties in parent and use `updateValueAndValidity` on each control. Hmm. It would be handy tho that it would be available to just call it on the parent.

Comment: See related question for some options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235156/angular-2-iterate-over-reactive-form-controls

Answer (score 20):

I had the same situation for me to update `FormGroup | FormArray` at nested level controls.

check this out(worked for me):

```js
/**
 * Re-calculates the value and validation status of the entire controls tree.
 */
function updateTreeValidity(group: FormGroup | FormArray): void {
  Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
    const abstractControl = group.controls[key];

    if (abstractControl instanceof FormGroup || abstractControl instanceof FormArray) {
      updateTreeValidity(abstractControl);
    } else {
      abstractControl.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; } | AbstractControl<any, any>[]'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; } | AbstractControl<any, any>[]'.ts(7053)

Answer (score 15):

It is not possible at the moment to update the descendants of an AbstractControl (FormGroup, ...) with the AbstractControl itself. Maybe in a future release it will be possible.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6170

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22166

update: a pull request is already open
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19829

Answer (score 11):

I solved my issue, which was similar to yours, by recursing the controls and manually triggering the update.
Probably this is not an optimal solution:

```
private triggerValidation(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        const group = (control as FormGroup);

        for (const field in group.controls) {
            const c = group.controls[field];

            this.triggerValidation(c);
        }
    }
    else if (control instanceof FormArray) {
        const group = (control as FormArray);

        for (const field in group.controls) {
            const c = group.controls[field];

            this.triggerValidation(c);
        }
    }

    control.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: false });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
validateFormFields(fields) {
    try {
      Object.entries(fields.controls).forEach((control: any) => {
        if (typeof control[0] == 'Array' 
        ) {
          this.validateFormFields(control[1]);
        } else {
          if (control[1].controls) {
            Object.entries(control[1].controls).forEach((c: any) => {
              c[1].touched = true;
            });
          } else {
            control[1].touched = true;
          }

        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Marking the control as touched is what was missing in other answers!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to trigger the validation on the control and its descendants, there is a workaround to call `updateTreeValidity` while it's not part of the public API:

```
(<any>form)._updateTreeValidity({ emitEvent: false });
```

The issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6170

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, one of the issues was that listening to the `valueChanges` observable and triggering `updateValueAndValidity` to run my validators caused an endless loop, so to resolve (and somewhat hacky ?) I created the component variable `validityCycleFired` and initialized as false, that I toggle and it prevents a runaway loop:

```
const fireValidityCheck = () => {
     if (this.validityCycleFired) return;
     this.validityCycleFired = true;
     this.passwordForm.get('old_password').updateValueAndValidity();
     this.passwordForm.get('new_password').updateValueAndValidity();
     this.passwordForm.get('confirm_new_password').updateValueAndValidity();
     setTimeout(() => this.validityCycleFired = false, 15);
     return;
};
this.passwordForm.valueChanges.subscribe(fireValidityCheck);
```