# Iterate Angular 2+ FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a FormArray and need to iterate through each of its members.

I see there is a `get` method in [the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl), but I don't see where to get the keys, or even the length.

How do I iterate a FormArray?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have a property `controls` in `FormArray` which is an array of `AbstractControl` objects. Check the specific documentation for [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) and you will see they also inherit from `AbstractControl` like the `FormControl` you posted.

Be aware that in the controls array you can have again inside `FormArray` or `FormGroup` objects besides `FormControl` objects because there can be nested groups or arrays.

Here is simple example:

```
for (let control of formArray.controls) {
   if (control instanceof FormControl) {
      // is a FormControl
   }
   if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
      // is a FormGroup  
   }
   if (control instanceof FormArray) {
      // is a FormArray
   }
}
```

Comment: I actually figured it out moments ago. Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Dunno why that's not documented.

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42235220/6826260) helped me: 

`this.form = this.fb.group({
            userIds: this.fb.array([])
        });


const userIds = this.form.controls.userIds as FormArray;

        userIds.value.forEach(key => {
            this.clinet.updateContactGroup(key, this.groupId).subscribe();}
        );`

Comment: You can iterate through `formArray.controls`, please see the answer below

Answer (score 29):

I solved this problem by looping through `formArray.controls` :

```
  formArray.controls.forEach((element, index) => {
    ...
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

If someone needs helps with iterating them in template (like I did), you can do this.

In this case we have FormArray where each child is FormControl

```
get myRows(): FormControl[] {
    return (this.<your form group>.get('<field name>') as FormArray).controls as FormControl[];
  }
```

And in template

```
*ngFor="let row of myRows"
```

Comment: oh btw. Now (Angular 14+) we have *Typed forms* so this anser is a little bit outdated. You should definetely start using them!

Comment: can you show an example

Comment: thanks @O-9, I was looking for same thing

Answer (score 1):

So, I had same situation, in my case:

```
adjustmentAmountArray: FormArray;
```

And I need sum of `contingencyUsed` of every FormArray item.

```
 adjustmentAmountArray.controls.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc + curr.value.contingencyUsed;
 });
```