# How to iterate a FormArray in HTML?

Tags: angular

I am trying to set up a simple FormArray in Angular and am having a hard time getting it to work.

What am I missing?

```
documentationForm: FormGroup;
documentationArray: FormArray;
defaultDocumentation = 1;

ngOnInit() {
    this.documentationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       id: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
}
```

When a file is added to uploader component, I am calling the following :

```
fileAddedToQueue(file) {
    this.documentationArray = this.documentationForm.get('id') as FormArray;
    this.documentationArray.push(this.addDocumentType());
}

private addDocumentType(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({ id: this.defaultDocumentation });
}
```

I put a bunch of console.log and it seems to be working as expected but I cannot get it working with my HTML.

```
<div formArrayName="id" *ngFor="let file of documentationForm.get('id').controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    test
</div>
```

I get the following :

```
Unhandled application error. Error: Cannot find control with name: 'id'
```

What am I doing wrong?  Everything seems to be correct from what I can see.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName#example

Comment: Whoops, idiot me forgot to add '<form [formGroup]=..........'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Reactive Forms with nested Form Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436145/angular-reactive-forms-with-nested-form-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are defining the formArray with id: this.formBuilder.array([]), but there should be a control inside formArray.

The correct way is to id: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.control('')])

Also inside this.formBuilder.array as you directly have this.formBuilder.control, you should not use formGroup in html.
Correct way is this:

```
<div formArrayName="id">
  <div *ngFor="let item of id.controls; let i=index">
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need documentationForm to be empty until the user takes an action.  The above code adds a formControl upon initialization.

Comment: This answer not correct, because `id.controls` may be return many different types like (FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray), ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49395590/2877427

Answer (score 0):

I think that your form initialization is wrong.Please try this:

```
documentationForm: FormGroup;
documentationArray: FormArray;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {

    this.documentationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: this.formBuilder.array([this.documentationArray])
     });

}
```

Comment: I tried the above but it added a formControl to this.documentationForm upon initialization.  I want it to be empty until the user adds a document.