# Angular 5 formgroup list controls or iterate them

Tags: angular, forms, web, angular-fullstack, formgroups

I am using angular 5 with formgorup and wish to iterate the controls, in order to create a dynamic component based on a form, the forms fields are given by an external data service (database etc.)

It is declares as follows

```
check = new FormGroup({
    firstName : new FormControl(true),
    lastName : new FormControl(false)
  });
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235156/angular-2-iterate-over-reactive-form-controls) explaining how to iterate the controls but It does not work. I try to use:

```
for(let item of this.check.controls){}
```

and get this is the chrome debug:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I can't access this.check.controls.keys or keys()

How can I iterate the keys?

Thanks

Comment: try ```for(let item in this.check.controls){console.log(item)}```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try use `Object.keys` method to get object keys

```
Object.keys(this.check.controls); // => ["firstName", "lastName"]
```

`this.check.controls` is object key/value paire structure if you want to get the keys of the object `{key1:value,key2:value}` you can use Object.keys method that return an array contains keys `['key1','key2']`

Comment: Great, works , could you please provide with some explanation for why it works?

Answer (score 3):

This Form Returning the Object of value not array of value

```
check = new FormGroup({
        firstName : new FormControl(true),
        lastName : new FormControl(false)
      });
```

If you want to get keys then you have to use The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop

```
KeyArray= Object.keys(this.check.controls)// ["firstName", "lastName"]
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stszta

Answer (score 1):

iterate over an object:

```
for(let item in this.check.controls){
    console.log(this.check.controls[item])
}
```

Comment: but this works :( check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-skndgl)

Answer (score 0):

this function works pretty good for me

```
public static ResetForm(form: FormGroup, config = {}) {
    const controls: string[] = Object.keys(form.controls);

    controls.forEach(key => {
      if (config[key] && config[key]["default"])
        form.get(key).setValue(config[key]["default"]);
      else form.get(key).setValue("");
      form.get(key).setErrors(null);
      form.get(key).markAsTouched();
    });
  }
```

if you want to set default value other then empty string, use config object as follow

```
ResetForm(this.form, {
      categories: {
        default: []
      }
    });
```