# FormGroup, get names of FormControl instead of numbers in Angular

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have in my code:

```
  private buildFormGroup() {
    const internalFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      document: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(this.minValueDocument)]],
      company: ['', [Validators.required]],
      typeClient: ['', [Validators.required]],
      textRequest: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.minNumberCharPerRequest)]],
      files: [''],
      myKey: ['myValue'],
    });

    return internalFormGroup;
  }
```

In my constructor I have this lines following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51593929):

```
this.formGroup = this.buildFormGroup();

for(let item in Object.keys(this.formGroup.controls)) {
  console.log(item)
}
for(let item in this.formGroup.controls) {
  console.log(this.formGroup.controls[item])
}
```

But, I get only numbers and the `value` appears empty!!!

[image]

I forget something? **How I can get the `name` of the control (not the its `Value`)?**

For my previous example: I would like to get: `document, company, typeClient, textRequest,files, myKey`

Comment: would adding `.value` here `console.log(this.formGroup.controls[item].value)` resolve your problem?

Comment: also, `this.formGroup.value` should give you all the current values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for...in` statement iterates over all **enumerable properties** of an object that are keyed by strings. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Since you are already extracting the keys from controls into an array, the for...in is looping through the array keys.

You have to either use `for...in` directly on formGroup.controls.

```
for(let item in this.formGroup.controls) {
  console.log(item)
}
```

Or use `for...of` instead

```
for(let item of Object.keys(this.formGroup.controls)) {
  console.log(item)
}
```

cheers