# Updating Angular 6 Form value in case corresponding dom native element value is modified by external library

Tags: dom, angular6, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I am experimenting cobrowsing with Angular 6 Forms.In co-browsing an opensource library togetherJS updates the DOM value of corresponding element for remote party.I have updated togetherJS related code in index.html(two line one in head and another in body) I have observed using ControlValueAccessor Form type DOM value of corresponding element is getting updated but FormControl value is not getting updated in view.
My question is how changes done by an external library on DOM elements can be reflected into angular 6 form control's element value in view.

One can get the code from below link:
https://github.com/srigaurav1986/Angular-Forms.git

How to reproduce:
1.Download code from above link.
2.Install dependencies using "npm install"
3.Run "ng serve -o"
4.open in browser "http://localhost:4200/controlvalueaccessor"
5.Click on "Start TogetherJs"
6.Copy the popped link in another browser window.
7.Update the "Name" field

We can see DOM field value is also getting updated on remote side but after pressing "Submit" button we can see FormControl value remains unaltered on remote side but changed on other side.

I tried using manually detecting changes using application.tick,markforcheck() and detectchanges() apis but no luck.Is there a way, where we can listen to some event on DOM element change and subscribe to it and also update the Formcontrol parameter values in such case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question lies in angular(6) property that it works on shadow DOM and only listen to the changes happening within angular zone , when the third party library  like TogetherJS updates DOM corresponding changes doesn't effect angular components as they are not subscribe to actual DOM native element.

[image]

In order to resolve this issue we did following :

- Register one call back in Form class constructer to capture  DOM “**change**” events triggered from Co-Browsing library i.e. happening outside angular zone   as mentioned below:

Code Snippet

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private elementRef: ElementRef,private _renderer: Renderer,private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef,private  app:ApplicationRef,private zone:NgZone) {
            zone.runOutsideAngular(() =>{

            window.document.addEventListener('change', this.change.bind(this));

        })
    }
```

- Define the eventHandler to perform below actions :

  - Run in Angular context using this.zone.run()
  - Use ElementRef to get the component’s template selector.
  - Run queryselector on input elements and compare with event’s outerHTML to check which element has changed in component.
  - Set the Formcontrol’s value for matching element.

PS: Here customerForm is  ControlValueAccesor FormGroup type of  instance. In your case it can be your form. We can generalize form( In case reactive) key traversal as mentioned in another SO post 
[Angular 2: Iterate over reactive form controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235156/angular-2-iterate-over-reactive-form-controls)

Code Snippet:

```
  change(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("DOM value changed" ,event);
        console.log("component value", this.elementRef.nativeElement);
        this.zone.run(() => { console.log('Do change detection here');
        //this.cdr.detectChanges();
        if(this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('input')[0].outerHTML === event.target.outerHTML)
        {
            console.log('Inside value updation');
            //this.customerForm.controls.name.value=event.target.value;
            this.customerForm.controls['name'].setValue(event.target.value);
        }
    });
        setTimeout(() =>{
            this.cdr.markForCheck();

        })

    }
```

This will set the respective values of elements(obviously via traversing loop) changed in component and validation should not fail as it’s happening in current context.
**The core idea of above details is how to capture change events happening outside angular zone and updating angular application accordingly.**

PS : I shall update the full code in github for other's perusal.