# Angular Iterate over Reactive Form Controls and Subchildren etc

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I need to iterate through all controls in Formbuilder, and children formbuilders  to  clear validators and updateValueAndValidity. How can I update answer from here to do so ?

[Angular 2: Iterate over reactive form controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235156/angular-2-iterate-over-reactive-form-controls)

```
Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
    this.form.controls[key].clearValidators();
    this.form.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
  });
```

This form here has formbuilders within formbuilders, etc. The answer above only affects top level children, not subchildren, etc

```
this.editSharedForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'name': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  'streetAddress': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  'city': [null, [Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(200)]],
  'zipcode': [null, [Validators.maxLength(10)]],
  'phoneNumber': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  'emailAddress': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.email]],
  'addressChangeReason': this.formBuilder.group({
    'addressChangeReasonId': [null,  [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],
    'addressChangeReasonCode': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    'addressChangeReasonDescription': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]]
  }),
  'addressSource': this.formBuilder.group({
    'sourceOfAddressId': [null, [Validators.required, validatorDropdown]],
    'sourceOfAddressCode': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    'sourceOfAddressDescription': [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]]
  })
});
```

}

2) 
Additionally, how can I just target 1 subchild (eg addressChange Reason) if needed ?
Following is not working

```
Object.keys(this.editSharedForm.get('addressChangeReason').controls).forEach(key => {
  this.editSharedForm.controls[key].clearValidators();
  this.editSharedForm.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
});
```

> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

Comment: did you try `this.editSharedForm['controls'][key].clearValidators();`

Comment: well I was basing from this answer which has many votes, let me try your way also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42235220/12555362

Comment: or you can do `this.editSharedForm.get(key).clearValidators();`

Answer (score 4):

So, if you want to call `clearValidators` and `updateValueAndValidity` on every nested `FormControl`, you must loop through all nested `FormGroups` and `FormArrays`.

It's quite simple as you can see in this quick example:

```
clearValidators(formGroup: FormGroup| FormArray): void {
  Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[key] as FormControl | FormGroup | FormArray;
    if(control instanceof FormControl) {
      console.log(`Clearing Validators of ${key}`);
      control.clearValidators();
      control.updateValueAndValidity()
    } else if(control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray) {
      console.log(`control '${key}' is nested group or array. calling clearValidators recursively`);
      this.clearValidators(control);
    } else {
      console.log("ignoring control")
    }
  });
```

For question 2)

Simply call

```
clearValidators(this.editSharedForm.get('addressChangeReason'))
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzsrq8

Comment: great, I will take a look at this, also how can I just target one child formbuilder below as in question 2?

Comment: simply call `clearValidators(this.editSharedForm.get('addressChangeReason')`

Comment: hi a winnen, ,have you tried the second part of your answer in stackblitz? receiving error Argument of type abstract control is not assignable to parameter of type, FormGroup FormArray,  can you try and update answer? Also I would give this new method a new name, so it does not override collide with original name, I gave points, anyway, please fix if you can, thanks !

Comment: maybe name it clearValidatorsNested? your call, thanks, please try question 2b in your stackblitz, was not working for me

Comment: what exactly does not work? you must be sure your AbstractControl is FormGroup or FormArray using type assert.

Comment: can you just show question 2 as an example in your stackblitz? you'll see what I mean, thanks

Comment: someone edited my answer 12 hours ago. i reverted it, so it will show the correct solution again. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cldrx3

Comment: You made my day. Thank you so much for your answer. it is helping me out for fixing bug in production. Thank you.