# Use Formbuilder with Enum in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to tie an Enum to Formbuilder names? Below, is an enum, and want to convert enum to its 
 string, and use with Formbuilder (rather than using strings in formbuilder)

Is this possible in Angular?

```
enum address{   
    city, 
    state, 
    zip
}

this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'city': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)]],
  'state': [null, [Validators.maxLength(200)]],
  'zip':[null,[Validators.maxLength(200)]]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason to use an enum?

I think an interface is more what you want:

```
interface address {
    city: string;
    state: string;
    zip: string;
}
```

If you go the interface route, you could take a look at my answer over here [Refer to FormBuilder Members in a Strongly Typed list in Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727651/refer-to-formbuilder-members-in-a-strongly-typed-list-in-angular-8/59728330?noredirect=1#comment105632658_59728330). It should apply to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: if I have enum on back-end like this: `public enum Gender
    {
        Male = 1,
        Female,
        Other       
    }`

and in Angular: `this.registerForm = this.fb.group({ gender: [1]}); I got an error when choosing other option which is string: `<label class="form-check-label mx-3">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="2" formControlName="gender"> Female
                </label>` 
How to convert it to int?