# Type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting into an error that says Type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

```html
<div *ngIf="form.controls && form.controls.length">
  <div *ngFor="let item of form.controls; let i = index">
    <ng-container [formArrayName]="i" [ngSwitch]="field[i].type">
      <div class="form-label-group mb-3 textPassword">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'inputText'">
          <input [ngClass]="{
                'border-danger':
                  field[i].field_name_key?.invalid &&
                  (field[i].field_name_key?.touched ||
                    field[i].field_name_key?.dirty)
              }" [type]="field[i].inputType == 'password' ? 'password' : 'text'" autocomplete="off" [maxLength]="field[i]?.maxLength" [formControlName]="field[i].field_name_key" class="form-control input-field" [placeholder]="
                field[i].is_mandatory
                  ? field[i].field_name_key + ' *'
                  : field[i].field_name_key
              " autofocus />
          <span *ngIf="
                field[i].field_name_key == 'CLIENTS_PASSWORD' ||
                field[i].field_name_key == 'CLIENTS_CONFIRMPASSWORD'
              ">
              <button (click)="showpassword(i, field[i].inputType)" *ngIf="field[i].inputType == 'password'"
                class="btn btn-link faeye-open" type="button">
                <fa-icon [icon]="faEye"></fa-icon>
              </button>
              <button (click)="showpassword(i, field[i].inputType)" *ngIf="field[i].inputType == 'text'"
                class="btn btn-link faeye-open" type="button">
                <fa-icon [icon]="faEyeSlash"></fa-icon>
              </button>
            </span>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'textArea'">
        <div class="form-label-group mb-3">
          <textarea [maxLength]="field[i].maxLength" [formControlName]="field[i]?.field_name_key" type="text" class="form-control" rows="1" [placeholder]="
                field[i].is_mandatory
                  ? field[i]?.field_name_key + ' *'
                  : field[i].placeholder
              "></textarea>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <div class="form-label-group mb-3">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'">
          <select class="form-control" [formControlName]="field[i].field_name_key">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="field[i]?.subFields; else nonSubFields">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
          <div class="mb-0">
            {{ field[i].field_name_key | translate }}
          </div>

          <ng-container *ngFor="
                  let subItem of item.controls[field[i].field_name_key]
                    .controls;
                  let j = index
                ">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline" [formArrayName]="field[i].field_name_key">
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [formControlName]="field[i].subFields[j].field_name_key" />
              <label class="form-check-label"><small>{{
                      field[i].subFields[j].field_name_key
                      | translate }}</small></label>
            </div>

          </ng-container>
          <!-- <hr class="mb-2 mt-2"> -->
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
          <div class="mb-0" *ngIf="field[i].field_name_key !== 'CLIENTS_ISDATAPRIVACYPOLICYDISPLAYED'" [formArrayName]="field[i].field_name_key">
            {{ field[i].field_name_key | translate }}
          </div>
          <ng-container *ngFor="
                let subItem of item.controls[field[i].field_name_key].controls;
                let j = index
              ">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline" *ngIf="
              field[i].subFields[j].field_name_key !==
              'GUARDIAN_NAME'
            ">
              <input [formControlName]="field[i].subFields[j].field_name_key" id="{{ field[i].field_name_key}} " name='field_name_key ' class="form-check-input" type="radio" [value]="field[i].subFields[j].field_name_key + j" />
              <label class="form-check-label">{{
                  field[i].subFields[j].field_name_key
                  | translate  }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-label-group mb-3" *ngIf="
                  field[i].subFields[j].field_name_key ===
                  'GUARDIAN_NAME'
                ">
              <!-- <label ><small>{{'GUARDIAN_NAME' | translate}}</small></label> -->
              <input type="text" autocomplete="off" [formControlName]="field[i].subFields[j].field_name_key" class="form-control input-field" maxlength="100" />
            </div>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #nonSubFields>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input [formControlName]="field[i].field_name_key" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">{{field[i].field_name_key | translate}}</label>
          </div>
          <hr class="mb-2 mt-2">
        </ng-container>
      </ng-template>
      <div class="text-danger" *ngIf=" item.controls[field[i].field_name_key || null]?.invalid  && item.controls[field[i].field_name_key || null]?.touched && 
          item.controls[field[i].field_name_key || null]?.errors?.required
        ">
        {{ field[i].field_name_key | translate}} is required
      </div>
      <div class="text-danger" *ngIf=" item.controls[field[i].field_name_key || null]?.invalid  && item.controls[field[i].field_name_key || null]?.touched && 
          item.controls[field[i].field_name_key || null]?.errors?.errorMessage
        ">
        {{ field[i].errorMessage | translate}}
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

found a few issues in the GitHub repository, but helped nothing.
Below is the link for code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-l7n4qg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated code its formgroup

Comment: It looks like FormGroups don't provide an iterator, so you'll have to go over them more manually

Comment: any idea on that @ CertainPerformance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235156/angular-2-iterate-over-reactive-form-controls

Comment: i am facing that on html as well  how to fix that manually on html @CertainPerformance
then link you have given fixed for ts fucntion

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414340) on that question - `in` will give you the property names, which you can use to get the controls

Comment: This worked for me thanks but same issue i am facing on html too
 <div *ngFor="let item of form.controls; let i = index">
    <ng-container [formArrayName]="i" [ngSwitch]="field[i].type">
</div></div>

form.controls giving same error