# Removing first character of each value in a object

Tags: javascript, object

What I have is:

```
routeLinks = {
    Store: '/store',
    Department: '/department',
    Home: '/home'
}
```

What I want is:

```
routeLinks = {
    Store: 'store',
    Department: 'department',
    Home: 'home'
}
```

i.e. modified object values with first character removed

Answer (score 4):

Use `slice`:

```js
const routeLinks = { Store: '/store', Department: '/department', Home: '/home' };

const res = Object.entries(routeLinks).reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[k] = v.slice(1), a), {});

console.log(res);
```

Or just use `for...in`:

```js
const routeLinks = { Store: '/store', Department: '/department', Home: '/home' };

for (let k in routeLinks) {
  routeLinks[k] = routeLinks[k].slice(1);
}

console.log(routeLinks);
```

Comment: I am getting an error with first solution: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

Comment: What environment are you using? TypeScript? Node?

Comment: I am using typescript

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45422573/10221765) on how to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the object with [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) the value:

```js
var routeLinks = {
  Store: '/store',
  Department: '/department',
  Home: '/home'
}
for(var k in routeLinks){
  routeLinks[k] = routeLinks[k].substring(1);
}
console.log(routeLinks);
```

Update: Solution using `forEach()` and arrow function (`=>`)

```js
var routeLinks = {
  Store: '/store',
  Department: '/department',
  Home: '/home'
};
Object.keys(routeLinks).forEach(k => routeLinks[k] = routeLinks[k].substring(1));
console.log(routeLinks);
```

Comment: Could you suggest a solution using lambda expression rather than for loop?

Comment: @AshishKumar, please see the second answer:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional version that doesn't mutate the input

```js
routeLinks = {
    Store: '/store',
    Department: '/department',
    Home: '/home'
};

const trimStart = obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, key) => ({...result, [key]: obj[key].substr(1) }), {});

console.log(trimStart(routeLinks));
```