# Delete data from object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below object and need to delete the column from the result, I will get the column name dynamically. Could you please help me how to delete the column and its corresponding object based on column name `{"columnname":"couln2", "datatype":null}`
Array is:

```
{
"tabl1":
{"tablename":"tabl1","tablecolumns":"yes","patternCheckStatus":true,
"columns": [{"columnname":"column1","datatype":"Numeric","patternregex":"jjj"},{"columnname":"column2","datatype":"UpperCase","patternregex":"hkl;;"}]},
"table2":{"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"yes","patternCheckStatus":null,
"columns":[{"columnname":"t2column","datatype":"Alphabetic"}]
}}
```

```js
let arr = 
    {"tabl1":{"tablename":"tabl1","tablecolumns":"yes","patternCheckStatus":true,"columns":[{"columnname":"column1","datatype":"Numeric","patternregex":"jjj"},{"columnname":"column2","datatype":"UpperCase","patternregex":"hkl;;"}]},"table2":{"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"yes","patternCheckStatus":null,"columns":[{"columnname":"t2column","datatype":"Alphabetic"}]}}


   

    const result = arr.reduce((a, {tablename, tablecolumns, columnname, datatype})   => {
        a[tablename] = a[tablename] || {tablename, tablecolumns, columns: []};
        if (columnname)
          a[tablename].columns.push({columnname, datatype});
        return a;
      },{})
    console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: Share the resulting array as well that you need

Comment: you mean delete the property `column` and delete `tabl2_colu`? Where is `tabl2_colu`?

Comment: @Ahsan ,@nopole, please see the updated array details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of some columns in array, then you can use `Object.entries` while `map` your array into another array:

```
let propertyName = 'tablename';
arr.map(s=> Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(s).filter(([k, v]) => k!= propertyName)))
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
    {"tablename":"table1","tablecolumns":"yes"},
    {"tablename":"table1","columnname":"col1","datatype":"Alphabetic"},
    {"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"yes"},
    {"tablename":"table2","columnname":"tabl2_colu","datatype":null},
    {"tablename":"table2","columnname":"tab2_col2","datatype":"Numeric"}
];

const result = arr.reduce((a, {tablename, tablecolumns, columnname, datatype})   => {
    a[tablename] = a[tablename] || {tablename, tablecolumns, columns: []};
    if (columnname)
        a[tablename].columns.push({columnname, datatype});
    return a;
    },{})

let propertyName = 'tablename';
console.log(Object.values(result)
    .map(s=> Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(s)
        .filter(([k, v]) => k!= propertyName))));
```

**UPDATE:**

You can filter your array based in `columnname`:

```
let columnname = 'column2';
obj.tabl1.columns = obj.tabl1.columns.filter(f=> f.columnname != columnname);
```

An example:

```js
let obj = { "tabl1":
  { "tablename": "tabl1", "tablecolumns": "yes", "patternCheckStatus": true,
  "columns": [{ "columnname": "column1", "datatype": "Numeric", "patternregex": "jjj" },
  { "columnname": "column2", "datatype": "UpperCase", "patternregex": "hkl;;" }] }, };

let columnname = 'column2';
obj.tabl1.columns = obj.tabl1.columns.filter(f=> f.columnname != columnname);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: thansk for the answer but i am getting below error ,
Property 'Fromentries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.ts

Comment: @user2319726 it looks like you need to add `"lib": ["es2017"]` into your settings. [Here yo can read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422573/property-entries-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor) :)

Comment: I need to remove complete columnname object , i think now its deleting only column name key value,
{
"tabl1":
{"tablename":"tabl1","tablecolumns":"yes","patternCheckStatus":true,
"columns": [{"columnname":"column1","datatype":"Numeric","patternregex":"jjj"},
}}

Comment: @user could you write the desired output?

Comment: Please see the below ,

before delete:
{
"tabl1":
{"tablename":"tabl1","tablecolumns":"yes","patternCheckStatus":true,
"columns": [{"columnname":"column1","datatype":"Numeric","patternregex":"jjj"},{"columnname":"column2","datatype":"UpperCase","patternregex":"hkl;;"}]},
}

expected after deleting
{
"tabl1":
{"tablename":"tabl1","tablecolumns":"yes","patternCheckStatus":true,
"columns": [{"columnname":"column1","datatype":"Numeric","patternregex":"jjj"}]},
}

Comment: is it possible to achieve the above  ?

Comment: thanks for the answer .. how to make table name as dynamic .. now you used tabl1 but i will not no the table name and i will only get column name ..

Comment: @user2319726 you can get your desired object by using square brackets: `let key='tabl1'; ` and then you can use like this `obj[key]`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand your question correctly but I think you want to delete a specific object having a specific `columnname` value from the `arr`.
You can filter the arr like this:

```
function deleteColumn (column) {
  let newArr = arr.filter(item => {
     return item.columnname !== column
  })
  return newArr
}
```

Then you can run:

```
deleteColumn('tabl2_colu') // Will return an array without object having any columnname = 'tabl2_colu'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. please see the updated array

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to loop through the array of objects, find the one you want to delete by the mean of its property identifier and them just remove that object from the array:

```
arr = [
{"tablename":"table1","tablecolumns":"yes"},
{"tablename":"table1","columnname":"col1","datatype":"Alphabetic"},
{"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"yes"},
{"tablename":"table2","columnname":"tabl2_colu","datatype":null},
{"tablename":"table2","columnname":"tab2_col2","datatype":"Numeric"}
];

function remove_object_by_colname( colname )
  arr.forEach(function( arrayItem, index ) {
    if ( arrayItem.columnname == colname ) {
      arr.splice( index, 1 );
    }
  };
} );

remove_object_by_colname( 'tabl2_colu' ); // Will remove the 4th object from arr.
```