# Angular 4 with es2018

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

Is possible to use "es2018" into "lib" in tsconfig.json in Angular 4 where typescript upper version allowed is 2.4.0?

I'm having this problem:

```
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (42574:38)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       Object.keys(messages).forEach(language => {
|         if (language in onboardingConfig.customMessages) {
|           finalMessages[language] = { ...messages[language],
|             ...onboardingConfig.customMessages[language]
|           };
```

Can you help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Looks like you set target, not lib. Yes it is possible, it's done all the time. Changing lib doesn't affect the emitted JavaScript.

Comment: Here's a related question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45422950/1915893