# How to write fetch synchronously?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new in javascript/typescript I write blackjack app using typescript and in one player game I have bot as second player.
His script looks like this:

```js
        const botTurn = (bot : Player) =>{
            while(bot.Points < 21)
            {
                if(bot.Points < 18)
                {
                    hitMe();
                }
                else
                {
                    var random = Math.random();
                    if(random < 0.5)
                    {
                        hitMe();
                    }
                    else{
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            stay();
        }
```

and hitMe looks like this:

```js
        const hitMe = () =>
        {
            fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/' + deckId + '/draw/?count=1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                deckLenght = data.remaining;
                for(let card of data.cards)
                {
                    var newCard = getCardData(card);
                    players[currentPlayer].Hand.push(newCard);
                    renderCard(newCard, currentPlayer);
                    updatePoints();
                    updateDeckLenght();
                    check();
                }
            });
        }
```

So botTurn doesn't wait for hitMe to finish and my browser hangs
How to fix that?

Comment: you cant write an asynchronous function as synchronous. consider using async/await.

Comment: how to do that, like I said I new in ts?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Async/await it will be better for your case and easier

```
const hitMe = async () =>
        {
         let response = await fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/' + deckId + '/draw/?count=1');
              let data = await response.json();
                deckLenght = data.remaining;
                for(let card of data.cards)
                {
                    var newCard = getCardData(card);
                    players[currentPlayer].Hand.push(newCard);
                    renderCard(newCard, currentPlayer);
                    updatePoints();
                    updateDeckLenght();
                    check();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Yes, but no, the relevant usage of `async`/`await` will be in `botTurn` not in `hitMe` (where the OP can just `return` the promise chain)

Comment: When I use async, then I got this error: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or 
include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.

Comment: But I don't have where to change this options

Comment: @Dante this might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45422573/1915893 It's a missing property rather than a missing object, but the solution is the same.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot expect a synchronous-based scoped value by wrapping an asynchronous operation with a synchronous operation.

although you can try to finalize your logic inside resolver, ie: then(result)