# adding lib to typescript config causes regression in compilation

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

i added

```
"lib": [
      "ES2020.Promise",
    ],
```

to my ts config because i needed to use `promise.allSettled()`, however, this caused a regression to my compile time checks as it's now failing on built in javascript functions like

```
Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'ConditionalAttributeEntity[][]'
const conditionalAttributes = conditionalAttributesUnprocessed.flat();

Parameter 'component' implicitly has an 'any' type.
.filter(component => _.has(component, 'componentList'))
```

before these worked fine

my config looks like this

```
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "lib": [
      "ES2020.Promise",
    ],
```

Is there anything i can do to more modularly use `promise.allSettled()` while keeping compile time checks the same?

Comment: can you try `ES2021.Promise`?

Comment: ts throws error saying that's not a valid lib

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45422950/1915893

Comment: right so reading from that, i used the most granular version by doing `.Promise` -- is there something more i'm missing from that post?

Comment: Add lib esnext to config

Comment: that will give me the most up to date, which is the problem here i think? But i ended up adding es2019 (same as my target) and that worked

Comment: Right of course, that's the obvious solution. I totally missed that. When you customize lib you have to specify your version of the standard for the library types explicitly

Comment: Is there an accepted solution that can be posted?