# How to filter by region and remove it from the resulting array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array structure:

```
const values = [{
    "region": "US", "content": "content 1", "value": "value1"
}, {
    "region": "US", "content": "content 2", "value": "value2"
}, {
    "region": "US", "content": "content 3", "value": "value3"
}, {
    "region": "LA", "content": "content 4", "value": "value4"
}, {
    "region": "LA", "content": "content 5", "value": "value5"
}, {
    "region": "LA", "content": "content 6", "value": "value6"
}, {
    "region": "LA", "content": "content 7", "value": "value7"
}]
```

and I am trying to transform it into the following - notice the `region` key is gone from the resulting object inside the output array:

```
const output = [{
    "US": [
        {"content": "content 1", "value": "value1"},
        {"content": "content 2", "value": "value2"},
        {"content": "content 3", "value": "value3"}
    ],
    "LA": [
        {"content": "content 4", "value": "value4"},
        {"content": "content 5", "value": "value5"},
        {"content": "content 6", "value": "value6"},
        {"content": "content 7", "value": "value7"}
    ]
}]
```

So far this is what I have tried:

```
let outputValues = [];

values.forEach(currentElement => {
    outputValues[currentElement.region].push(currentElement);
})

console.log(outputValues);
```

The above solution gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Not sure why.

I have tried also:

```
# 1st option
outputValues[currentElement.region] = currentElement;

# 2nd option
outputValues[currentElement.region] = [];
outputValues[currentElement.region].push(currentElement);
```

But that adds only the last element from the main `values` array. What am I missing here?

Comment: `currentElement.region` is a string, but you have defined `outputValues` as an array, which has integer indices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not want to keep the original objects, you could take the unwanted key as grouping value and delete this property while grouping.

```js
const
    values = [{ region: "US", content: "content 1", value: "value1" }, { region: "US", content: "content 2", value: "value2" }, { region: "US", content: "content 3", value: "value3" }, { region: "LA", content: "content 4", value: "value4" }, { region: "LA", content: "content 5", value: "value5" }, { region: "LA", content: "content 6", value: "value6" }, { region: "LA", content: "content 7", value: "value7" }],
    result = Object.groupBy(values, o => {
        const group = o.region;
        delete o.region;
        return group;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A solution without `groupBy` and without mutating data:

```js
const
    values = [{ region: "US", content: "content 1", value: "value1" }, { region: "US", content: "content 2", value: "value2" }, { region: "US", content: "content 3", value: "value3" }, { region: "LA", content: "content 4", value: "value4" }, { region: "LA", content: "content 5", value: "value5" }, { region: "LA", content: "content 6", value: "value6" }, { region: "LA", content: "content 7", value: "value7" }],
    result = values.reduce((r, { region, ...o}) => {
        (r[region] ??= []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Brilliant, was not aware of this `groupBy` function.

Comment: this is working perfectly for vanilla JS but with React using Typescript it gives me the following error: `TS2339: Property `groupBy` does not exist on type `ObjectConstructor` and I have changed my lib to include `es2017`as instructed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422573/property-entries-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor but still not working, the source can't compile, any ideas?

Comment: You can avoid mutating `values` in the first example by deep copying it. Various methods, for example (if just using primitive property types):
`result = Object.groupBy(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(values)), o ...`