# There are typescript dictionaries like as3?

Tags: typescript, actionscript-3

I'm migrating from AS3 to Typescript and I see that in Typescript there are no dictionaries

is there any way to create a dictionary key value with the key can be one: any?

Comment: What makes you think there are no Dictionaries in TS? See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174182/typescript-looping-through-a-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

A Map's keys can be any value (including functions, objects, or any primitive), which is similar to Dictionary. I think that's what you mean by "the key can be one: any"?

Otherwise, you'd typically just use an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) if you are able to use strings for the keys.